# How do I use a GroupStyle that is defined in Window.Resources programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have this snippet of code in an XAML file. The question is, how do I use this Resource to make a ListView object show its Header in the list that I generate during run-time (loading from a file)?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <GroupStyle x:Key="DD">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Gray" Height="35"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here is what I have in C#:

```
ListView lv = new ListView() {
    ItemsSource = qualities,
    DisplayMemberPath = "name"
};
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lv.ItemsSource);
lv.GroupStyle.Add((GroupStyle)Application.Current.Resources["DD"]);
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("type"));
```

But `Application.Current.Resources` returns null all the time!

Comment: why do you use `Application.Current.Resources` if resource is stored in `<Window.Resources>`?

Comment: Because I am a complete beginner to this XAML-C# programming and I have no idea what else I could use! This is what I have found on StackOverflow that seemed to work for others!

Comment: Okay.. Thank you ASh, for the help. Apparently, if I move the GroupStyle object into the App.xaml from the MainWindow.xaml, it works. Thank you very much for the awesome call!

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your group style on the `Window` resources and not in the application resources. In order to access resources there, you can use one of the following options:

- [`Resources["DD"]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources?view=net-5.0) - This accesses the `Resources` property of the `Window` directly by key

  > Gets or sets the locally-defined resource dictionary.
- [`FindResource("DD")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=net-5.0) - The will search in other resource dictionaries in scope, too

  > If the resource is not found on the calling element, the parent element in the logical tree is searched next, then the application, then themes, and finally system resources. This lookup methodology is identical to how the tree is searched if a resource were requested by a dynamic resource reference in markup.

If your group style is used in other places as well, you can alternatively move it to the application resources if that is more suitable in your case, then your code will work.

Comment: I have tried `this.Resources["DD"]` and `this.FindResource("DD")` as well. They both return null!

Comment: @RainyDagger Is the code that you provided in the code-behind of the window? Are you sure that there is group style is still in the `Window.Resources` and there is no typo in the resource key? Did you write `lv.GroupStyle.Add((GroupStyle)Resources["DD"]);` and alternatively `lv.GroupStyle.Add((GroupStyle)FindResource("DD"));`?

Comment: The resource key consists of two D characters. Having a typo would be hard! The `<GroupStyle>...</GroupStyle>` is indeed inside `<Window.Resources></Window.Resources>` and calling `this.Resources["DD"]` or `this.FindResource("DD")` return null whether I call them from the MainWindow.xaml.cs (Default name from Visual Studio) or a different class I define!

Comment: @RainyDagger This should work **but only in MainWindow.xaml.cs**, but even if the resource is not found, `FindResource` would throw an exception and not return `null`. There might be a different error.

Comment: @RainyDagger Did you place your code **before** the `InitializeComponent()` call in the constructor?  If so, **move the code to after that call**, otherwise the control is not initialized and the resource dictionary will return `null`.

Comment: Okay, so apparently it's not a `null`, but a `System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException`. Sorry for the confusion! It is way beyond the `InitializeComponent()` call! I am trying to get the DD Resource on a button click, after a file load. At that point, everything should be initialized, right?

Comment: @RainyDagger Can you share your XAML and code-behind file somewhere like PasteBin? Without the code it is hard to guess what the problem is.